# Avoid Overlap using Trim

Tags: javascript, html, svg

hi i have a following code,

```
<html>
    <body>
        <style> 
            div {
                border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
                padding: 10px 40px; 
                background: #dddddd;
                width: 300px;
                height : 300px;
            }
        </style>
        <div>
            <svg id="text">
                <text transform="rotate(127,128,64)" opacity="1" text-anchor="start" font-weight="regular" font-style="Normal" font-family="Segoe UI" font-size="12px" fill="#191919" y="68.25" x="128" id="caption">Revenue stackoverflow Revenue stackoverflow  </text>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

the out put of the text can be overlapped the out of the area or overlape to the next svg element. so i would like to show if the text overlap to the another element or out of the area need to perform trim operation.

example :Revenue stackove...

Answer (score 0):

Try with css ellipsis, like this:-

```
 div {
                border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
                padding: 10px 40px; 
                background: #dddddd;
                width: 300px;
                height : 300px;
                white-space: nowrap; 
                overflow: hidden;
                text-overflow: ellipsis; 
            }
```

Comment: no i need to show like this Revenue stackove...(...)

Comment: You should clearly write your question so that others can help you.